# Base Url PHP includes on WAMP

Tags: php, mysql, include, wamp, base-url

I am building a PHP mySQL site locally with WAMP.

in my WAMP www directory i have made subfolders for each website I am making. eg:

```
WAMP\www\site1\index.php
WAMP\www\site2\index.php
WAMP\www\site3\index.php
etc
```

my DB connection is stored in:

```
site1/connections/open.php
```

my PHP scripts are stored under:

```
site1/php/filename.php
```

when i am running a script i need to include the open.php connection. the only way i can get this to work is by using:

```
include '../connections/open.php';  // this goes at the top of the PHP script
```

I know that if i use this and then move to remote servers or move some directories around I will have problems accessing this file. I therefore want the path to be relative to the basedir or baseurl(/site1/).

I understand that when you use an include it is looking for a dir and not an url so I cant use anything like;

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

How do you go about sorting this out? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right on that URL part

> I understand that when you use an include it is looking for a dir and
>   not an url so I cant use anything like;
>
> $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
>
> How do you go about sorting this out? Thanks

You should try like this

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/myFolder/"
```

Or try this

```
getcwd()."/myFolder/"
```

But there is a difference between both of them [Try Googling]

Comment: hi, thanks but the problem is that this will just go from WAMP/www/ and not WAMP/www/site1/ i need to somehow make it relative to the subdir of my site.

Comment: Well you have to create some sort of config.php and Add an php CONSTANT like 'define('PRJ_FOLDER', 'site1/');' use it where required like 'echo PRJ_FOLDER'

Answer (score 0):

I think when you move to remote servers or move some directories around you will have no problems,because you are using relative path.
I think you should not use "$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']" and I think you should know what they mean!